# React: how to change the style property of one JSX element based on another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styling

I'm trying to do some styling with react. I've got a results page, and I want my results cards to stretch (a bit) to fill each line. To do that I'm using...

```
let body = {
  display: "flex",
  margin: "0% 10%",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
};
```

and...

```
let card = {
    fontSize: "90%", 
    flexBasis: "15rem",
    minWidth: "10rem",
    flexShrink: "1",
    flexGrow: "1",
}
```

My issue is that I also want all the results cards to be the same size. Normally, I'd think about using jQuery for this, but I'm using React and that's a bit awkward.

So, what I'm trying to do is pass the width information of the first results card (child component) back to the results page (parent component) with a callback function. Then, I intend to pass a "maxWidth" property to the other results cards using props. Note: this works, in the sense that I can pass width information back to the parent and I can style a results card using props.

The problem is that when I try to assign the width information to the props of one of the other results cards, it is undefined. I suspect this is because you can't update the state and take information from the state while a JSX element is rendering...

Any ideas about how I can achieve what I want? 
Any ideas about how I can somehow pause the render in order to update the state?

All the best

Parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Card from './Card.js';

class Body extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  };
  this.cardWidth = function (width) {
    this.state.cardWidth = width;
    console.log(this.state.cardWidth);
  }.bind(this);
};
render() {
  return (
    <div className="body" style={body}>
      <Card cardWidth={this.cardWidth}/>
      <Card style={{maxWidth:`${this.state.cardWidth}`}}/>
      <Card style={{maxWidth:`${this.state.cardWidth}`}}/>
    </div>
  );
};
};

let body = {
  display: "flex",
  margin: "0% 10%",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
};

export default Body;
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Card extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.cardref = React.createRef();
};
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.cardWidth) {
        this.props.cardWidth(this.cardref.current.offsetWidth);
    };
};
render() {
    return (
        <div className="card" style={(this.props.style)?(Object.assign({}, this.props.style, card)): card} ref={this.cardref}>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title" style={{fontSize: "100%"}}>Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text" style={pText}>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary" style={{fontSize: "80%"}}>Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
};

let card = {
    fontSize: "90%", 
    flexBasis: "15rem",
    minWidth: "10rem",
    // maxWidth: "15rem",
    flexShrink: "1",
    flexGrow: "1",
}

let pText = {
    display: "block",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: "4rem",
    fontSize: "80%"
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'd missed out px after the maxWidth property value. Now I have the problem that I need it to re-render on a view port resize event.

[Desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oodux.png)

Answer (score 0):

To make all the cards the same size, within a given space, can use `flex-grow`. For example if you set `flex-grow: 1` on all your cards then they will all grow to fill the extra space evenly. There is a nice diagram [on this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) also if you look for the 'flex-grow' heading.

Comment: I tried using flex-grow, my issue was that unless each row has the same number of cards, the cards on different rows will be different widths. Are you sure? If so I'll give it another go.

Comment: I see, I think that you're right and that the cards will be evenly sized within the space, so if you have fewer items each will be smaller.  Could you make the container size based upon the number of cards perhaps? So if a full row has 10 cards, and you have a row with 9, then the container is 9/10 the actual size. If you know how many cards you have before rendering?